# android super.onBackPressed() timing

Tags: android, android-activity

In general, should you call `super.onBackPressed()` FIRST in an overridden `onBackPress()` or at the end? Will the user notice any difference between the two code snippets below? I apologize I am new to Android. I know in theory what `super.onBackPressed()` does, but I am not sure if there is any difference in the code below.

---

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    /*
     * SOMETHING THAT TAKES A LONG TIME TO FINSIH
     */
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    /*
     * SOMETHING THAT TAKES A LONG TIME TO FINSIH
     */
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: `onBackPressed()` happens on the main thread so doing anything long running is probably a bad idea as your app will appear completely frozen.

Comment: This is valid question behind the lifecycle of the activity but I don't know why peoples are downvoting before understanding the question. My suggestion to Stackoverflow should give any negative points to downgrade people if questions are valid.

Answer (score 1):

When override close/end activity methods, it's best to keep super at the thend. You don't even have to have `super.onBackPressed()` if you don't want to kill the activity, but the activity should disappear.

Cheers